# Convert one column into one row in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a select statement which yields a single large column. What I would like to do is convert the one column into one row so that I can feed it into a another stored procedure. How could I transpose the table so that it is one single row? So far, I have tried `UNIPIVOT` but have not been able to get it working.

Here is the format of the current table (in reality, it's much longer with a variable amount of rows):

```
+------+
| Col1 |
+------+
|    1 |
|   56 |
|   83 |
|  345 |
| 4322 |
| 4456 |
+------+
```

which is stored in a local table `#localtable`

I would like to turn the above table into the below table:

```
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | col5 | col6 |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |   56 |   83 |  345 | 4322 | 4456 |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

as an intermediate step in converting it into the following comma-delimited string:

```
'1, 56, 83, 345, 4322, 4456'
```

With the goal of feeding it into an exec like:

```
exec myfunction '1, 56, 83, 345, 4322, 4456'
```

Comment: what does the function do?  can't the function just grab the values with a select statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this with the following query, creating my desired comma-delimited string:

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT  ',' + CAST(Col1 AS VARCHAR(50))
            FROM #localtable
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS listStr
```

Comment: You can omit the `TOP 1` here, since the `STUFF` only returns a single varchar (when not selecting from a table-source).

Comment: So just `select *`?

Comment: It would be `SELECT STUFF(...) As listStr`, just like you would do `SELECT 1 As listStr`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `string_agg()` in the most recent versions of SQL Server:

```
select string_agg(col, ', ')
from #localtable;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution that will work with older SQL Server version (where no `string_agg` is available):

```
--create test table
declare @tmp table (Col1 int)

--populate test table
insert into @tmp
values
 (    1)
,(   56)
,(   83)
,(  345)
,( 4322)
,( 4456)

--declare a variable that will contain the final result
declare @result varchar(4000) = ''

--populate final result from table
select @result = @result + ', ' + cast(Col1 as varchar) from @tmp

--remove first unnecessary comma
set @result = STUFF(@result, 1, 1, '') 

--print result
select @result as result
```

Result:

[image]